# Shorten function names in profling results with valgrind+kcachegrind

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind, kcachegrind

I work usually with valgrind+kcachegrind to profile C++ codes. A new code I am working with uses very long function names, so that the graphical results are a mess. I wonder how can one shorten the function names so that they fit in a small box.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a dirty workaround... you could be to write a script that does a find and replace for a list of function names for the files generated by Valgrind and then use kcachegrind to visualize the data.

Maybe you could shorten the function names in the code by using namespaces?